# Mysterious line break is being appended to ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using either .ajax or .load, I'm loading content from an .html page into or replace an element. In either case, the content is called and inserted and there is a mysterious new line (not a break element , but like a \n or \r) appended after my content from the .html file.

In chrome's element inspector it looks like:

```
<div class="loaded parent">
 // all my loaded content
</div>
"
(ghost line)
"
```

There are no breaks in the code so I have no idea where this is coming from.

.html:

```
<div id="ForgotPasswordForm" class="ajax">
 <h2>Reset Your Password test</h2>
 <div class="BlockContent">
 <p> Enter your email below to request a password reset. An email will be send with a reset link. </p>
 <p class="ErrorMessage" style="display:none"></p>
 <form action="/login.php?action=send_password_email" method="post" onsubmit="return check_forgot_password_form()">
 <div>
 <dl style="width: 270px;margin: 0 auto;height: 30px;">
 <dt style="float: left;width: 100px;text-align: right;margin:5px 5px 0 0;"> <span class="Required">*</span> Email Address: </dt>
 <dd style="float:left;font-size:12px;width:150px;">
 <input style="padding:4px;" type="text" class="Textbox" name="email" id="email" />
 </dd>
 </dl>
 <p class="Submit" style="text-align:center">
 <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
 </p>
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
</div>​
```

Script:

```
$('#recover-pass').click(
       function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //$('#login-content').load('/content/ResetPassword.html');
            $.ajax({
                  url: '/content/ResetPassword.html',
                  success: function(data) {
                        $('#login-content').replaceWith(data);
                        alert('Load was performed.');
                  }
            });
      });
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand where you load your content. However, can you try to remove the spaces there? <div class="loaded parent"></div>

Comment: Have you tried checking for white space at the end of the ajaxed file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most text file formats save the file with a final line break character at EOF. Assuming you're treating this html file like a server side include, that's probably causing your symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Try copy/pasting the code to a different editor (like notepad in windows).  Many text editors are able to use different OS's line breaks, and I've seen some that can't delete the line breaks of types other than the one it is set to use.  For example, one text editor put Mac line breaks at the end of the file, I open it in Windows and my text editor does not display or indicate those breaks at all.  Notepad pretty much just ignores everything it doesn't know about, so when you paste into there, it gets rid of the extra breaks.

Unless you are seeing the effect with ALL AJAX requests using ANY file, this is probably the culprit.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I was editing on Dreamweaver on a Mac. Popped it into Windows notepad and there was line break at the end. Sorry I dont have the rep to vote up.

Comment: You can still accept the answer, and in fact I would suggest doing so.  If you don't accept answers, you get a bad "rep" and people might not be as willing to try for you in the future.  :)