# newline on source code?

Tags: php

I'm making a simple global get configuration.

try to make a index.php

```
function config( $string ){
    require 'configuration.php';
    return $config[$string];
}

echo config('hello');
echo config('hello');
```

and a configuration.php

```
$config['hello'] = TRUE;
```

and yes as we can see it outputs 1.

but when we see the source, it will give us something like

[image]

sorry for the stupid question, but I just cant stop asking.

Thanks for looking in.

Comment: Something tells me your configuration file has white space in it. And, since you're reloading the config file every call to `config()`, they're being appended to the document,

Comment: oh my god after 6x checking. i got it. can we forget this guys ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any newlines before your `<?PHP` - Tag or after the `?>` in your `'configuration.php'` ? If so, remove them, because PHP outputs everything it sees directly to the browser, if it's not enclosed by PHP Tags.

Comment: its after not before, how could i missed that ?

Comment: Updated my answer. It's easy to miss that because - y'know - newlines are kind of invisible ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're requiring configuration.php inside the config function.  Any blank lines in configuration.php before the `<?php` or after the `?>` are being output to the page.

Consider moving the `require` line outside the `config` function.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: [Mysterious line break is being appended to ajax loaded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971585/mysterious-line-break-is-being-appended-to-ajax-loaded-content/4971820#4971820)

You probably have line breaks from a different OS, and your editor isn't capable of displaying them.  Some editors can, some ignore them.  So for instance, if I were to have edited the file on a Mac and left a blank line, then you open it in Windows, your text editor might not show you the blank line, and you might even have a hard time deleting it.

Try to copy/paste the code into something like Windows Notpad, then copy/paste it back out.  Notepad ignores everything it doesn't recognize.