# Weird line break added to ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I'm having the same problem explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971585/mysterious-line-break-is-being-appended-to-ajax-loaded-content) except the mysterious line breaks is added at the beginning of my loaded content.

When using Firebug or different inspector, here's what I have:

```
<div class="form_item" style="display: block;"><!-- Start of Ajax loaded content -->
                                                  <--- ghost line
  <div class="view_question">
  <div class="view_edit" style="display:none">
<!-- End of Ajax loaded content --></div>
```

And this ghost line results in a line break when displaying content.
Also, this problem happens only for one of my ajax request. I'm actually using it inside the jquery **droppable & sortable**.
Here's my code if you can spot something wrong:

```
$(".form_container").sortable({
        // ...
        receive: function(event,ui) {
            // ...
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'html',
                data: '',
                type: 'GET',
                url: link,
                success: function (data){
                    // ...
                    $('.form_container').find('.form_item').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I've already been through my code to delete empty lines at the end of my files but nothing changed.

I'm waiting for your precious answer. Thanks!

**---  1st EDIT ---**

The `link` is a simple URL. That URL is a controller that send back pure HTML. When checked with Firebug, the response has no line break in it.

**---  2nd EDIT ---**

The element I'm dropping on my sortable list looks something like this

```
<div class="form_item"><a href="link">....</a></div>
```

Then I get the `link` value in JS in order to perform the request.

I tried to change this line

```
$('.form_container').find('.form_item').html(data);
```

for

```
$('.form_container').find('.form_item').html('Test');
```

And then I've no problem. If I try to debug `data` (with alert(data) or in Firebug), the HTML is correct, no line breaks. :(

Comment: this link, what is on the other side? an page? an web service? what? can you post here what are you requesting and what is the source to that request?

Comment: I edited my question. I use the same URL(controller) for different ajax request, and only this one seems to have this problem. :/

Comment: Is there nothing you can do with your CSS to fix it? I mean if you change your styles, then whitespace in your HTML should not affect anything. Look into `display: inline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me its seems to be server side issue .

Possible debug spots :

1. server side script from where the response is generated
2. trim the data if not sure of server side script

   `$('.form_container').find('.form_item').html(data.trim());`
3. use CSS to ignore the spaces on parent element e.g

   `<div class="form_item" style="display: block;white-space:normal">`

   Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to tighten up the spaces in the HTML?

Spaces / line-breaks in code can be interpreted as textnodes and rendered as spaces and/or line breaks on the page.

See if this works:

```
<div class="form_item" style="display: block;"><div class="view_question">
```

Comment: I wish i Could but how ? The code between `<div class="form_item">..</div>` is the data I get from ajax. And when I generate this data, I don't have any line break. That's why I don't know where to look!

Comment: Is your closing `<div>` on a separate line?  If so, what I think you should do is place them on the same line: 
`<div class="form_item"></div>` without any spaces in between.

Comment: Nope, it's already on the same line. I'm going to edit my post.